# mat-slide-toggle change all value on all products and value are diffrent

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using slide-toggle Material to activate or not a product in my app. My problems are:

1. When I click one slidetoggle, it changes all value in all products.
2. my value is different than I set. Show my photo console.

[image]

[image]

active: 1 --> Function submit.
0 --> function slide-toggle

My html code:

```
<form [formGroup]="activeHomeboxPForm">
        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" id="active" [(ngModel)]="active" (change)="onChange($event)" (click)="onActiveHomeboxP(item.homeboxpackage_id)">
        </mat-slide-toggle>
        {{active}}
      </form>
```

My ts code:

```
   this.activeHomeboxPForm = this.fb.group({
      'active': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      'homeboxpackage_id': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });

populateFormHomeboxP() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.hsP.getHomeboxPById(params['id']).subscribe(
          homeboxP => {
            this.homeboxP = homeboxP;
            this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['active'].setValue(homeboxP.active);
            this.activeHomeboxPForm.controls['homeboxpackage_id'].setValue(homeboxP.homeboxpackage_id);
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }

  onActiveHomeboxP(homeboxpackageid) {
    this.loading = true;
    if (confirm('Are you sure to change Status?')) {

      let editHomeboxp = new HomeboxP(
        this.activeHomeboxPForm.value
      );
      editHomeboxp.homeboxpackage_id = homeboxpackageid;
      console.log(editHomeboxp) // --> active: 1
      this.hsP.activatehomeboxp(editHomeboxp).subscribe(
        result => {
          if (result === true) {
            Materialize.toast('HomeboxPacket updated successfully', 4000);
            this.router.navigate(['/main/homeboxpackage']);
          } else {
            this.loading = false;
          }
        },

        error => {
          this.loading = false;
        }
      );
    }
  }
  onChange(value) {
    if (value.checked === true) {
      this.active = 1;
      console.log(1);  //1
    } else {
      this.active = 0;
      console.log(0); //0
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is because you are using the same ngModel variable for all of them

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="inventory_qtd">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Venda </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let products">
        <div *ngIf="products.status === 1">
          <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="true" (change)="onChange($event, products.id)">Disponível</mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="products.status === 0">
          <mat-slide-toggle [checked]="false" (change)="onChange($event, products.id)">Disponível</mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>

      </td>
    </ng-container>
```

Code:

```
onChange(value, product_id) {
if (value.checked === true) {
  this.active = 1;
  console.log({ checked: true, product_id: product_id});
} else {
  this.active = 0;
  console.log({ checked: false, product_id: product_id});
}}
```